# strtotime within existing PHP function

Tags: php, mysql

I have and existing PHP function that updates MySQL records like this.  I need to set a date field but am having trouble formatting the PHP correctly.  Currently this is working fine:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'adverts_email', 't@t.com');
```

the t@t.com is regular text.

For the expiration date I want to use strtotime('+20 days'); to write it out in a unix timestamp format like 1449203160 which translates out to human form as Dec 4, 2015 @ 4:26.

I 've tried many variations of .'strtotime('+20 days');'. or '.strtotime('+20 days');.' with and without the ; and it does not work.  I am unsure if the issue is the syntax or the strtotime use when I should use DATETIME or some other method or a combination of two problems?

Broke:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_expiration_date', 'strtotime('+20 days');');
```

Comment: The syntax highlighting shows your error. Error reporting would also catch this.

Comment: @JohnConde okay, thanks.  I updated the question to include a variation to handle use of strtotime or DATETIME too...not sure if that helps add value to the question or I can delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, the syntax highlighting shows the problem. Here's solution that should work:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_expiration_date', strtotime('+20 days'));
```

This assumes that the `_expiration_date` field is a integer/unix timestamp, but it's more likely that the field is `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` type. As such, this might work better:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_expiration_date', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+20 days')));
```